# add shipping information programmatically

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to add shipping information to order programmatically(I have some policy for it),how can I do it?

my idea is  add submit handler in form ,then load profile and set it in `form_state` values but not worked and it only has default profile information of that user (profile_id different with 3)

my code :

```
function chapboodev_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    if($form_id=='commerce_checkout_form_shipping'){

//        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'chapboodev') . '/chapboo_refresh_block.js');
//        unset($form['customer_profile_shipping']);
//        hide($form['customer_profile_shipping']);
        $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][]='chapboodev_custom_sub';
        ym($form);
    }
    //    ym($form_id);
}

function chapboodev_custom_sub($form,&$form_state) {
        $form_state['values']['customer_profile_shipping']['customer_profile']=commerce_customer_profile_load(3);

}
```

Comment: There's no shortcuts, you need to write a full shipping module if you want more advanced calculation. Trying to affect it by form alter will never work as the guts of the method won't be known to Commerce. See [Commerce Flat Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) for a full code example

Comment: @Clive I just want to have custom select profile in shipping information.( shipping information like ,address, telephone, name va ...) I create a block with that what I want , I want put it in shipping information page and hide origin, then when user select a customer shipping profile , in submit of form put it as value of origin  shipping information pane.

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127611/update-shipping-profile-on-user-update)?

Comment: @Clive it is about default user profiles, I want there create a relation between user information and  customer profile shipping information,in there my problem was when user edit information submit even user default profile exists, it is instead update create new one, in this question my problem is in only in customer shipping information pane, I want it is different with default ( I have custom bock that want get selected profile id from it )
thanks for your attention master Clive

Comment: _it is instead update create new one_. Yep, believe it or not, it's _supposed to_. This is to ensure editing a profile in the future won't change the shipping/billing details attached to an existing order. There isn't a way around it without some serious re-engineering of the involved modules (I've checked, many times).

Comment: @Clive  oh yes, tnx, I get other question reason :).